# Regex to find number of occurrences of a word in np++

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

In `np++` there is a count option for number of occurrences of a word, and mark, and highlight..  But I need to find the only the first three occurrences of a word.

```
zero word one word two word three word four word five word six
```

So when I search it highlights these `word one word two word`.

I tried `[word]{4}` but to find that word - `(\w+\s+){3}` to find three consecutive.  What I need is to make it highlight or select from the first `word` word to the third one.

Comment: Try `^(?:(?:(?!\bword\b).)*\bword\b){3}`

Comment: thanks, it works great..  should I close the question now or what?

Comment: I have posted an answer with explanations, please consider accepting since it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:(?:(?!\bword\b).)*\bword\b){3}
```

The [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xA4qK7/1)

The regex works like this: it matches the beginning of the line (`^`), then tries to match any text that is not `word` up to the first whole word `word`, and the whole group (all the characters other than `word` and the `word` itself) is quantified with the limiting quantifier `{3}` to require exactly 3 occurrences.

The `(?:(?!\bword\b).)*` construct is called a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) and can be used as a synonym for a negated character class for *multicharacter sequences*.

[image]